# Why does the value of x not change, and how would you change it? -Understanding Methods

Tags: java, methods, int

```
    static void number(int x){
        x=42;
    }


 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x =17;
    number(x);
    System.out.println(x);
```

why is the value printed out still 17 and not 42? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
number(x);
```

passes the *value* of `x` into `number`. Nothing that links back to `x` is passed at all. Inside `number`, the `x` argument you've declared is not in any way linked to the `x` variable in `main`; it just receives the value that you passed into `number`. Assigning to the argument (`x = 42`) just changes the value of the argument, not the variable in `main`.

This is called *pass-by-value*, meaning that whenever you pass a variable into a method, the **value** of that variable is passed, not anything about the variable itself. Exactly the same thing happens here:

```
x = 17;
y = x;
y = 42;
System.out.println(x); // 17
System.out.println(y); // 42
```

`y = x` just takes the *value* of `x` and puts it in `y`. There's no ongoing link between `x` and `y`.

So how would you change it? The usual approach is have `number` *return* a new value:

```
int number(int val) {
    return val * 2;
}
```

Then in `main`:

```
x = 17;
x = number(x);
System.out.println(x); // 43
```

Sometimes, people get confused by pass-by-value when it involves object references. Variables directly contain primitives like `int`, but they don't directly contain objects; they contain object *references*. So consider:

```
List<String> l1 = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Now, `l1` contains a value that is a reference to the linked list object. Now suppose we do this:

```
List<String> l2 = l1;
```

What happened there? Do we have one list, or two?

The answer is, of course, one: The value we copied from `l1` to `l2` is the reference to the list, which exists elsewhere in memory.

Key points in summary:

- When you pass a "variable" into a method, it's the *value* of the variable that gets passed (**always** — Java is purely pass-by-value [some other languages have something called pass-by-reference, where a reference to the variable is passed, but Java doesn't have that)
- The same thing happens when you assign a variable to another variable
- Object references are values that tell the JVM where the object is in memory

Answer (score 0):

Java is pass by value So when you passes `x` which is defined in `main()` to `number()` method ,only the value is copied to function parameter `x` and no address is passed unlike `C` pointers.So the value you get is `17` because it is not changed.

Comment: C would have identical behavior here.

Comment: @chrylis I was referring about `C pointers` whaich have memory address